# Use user selected image as canvas background

Tags: c#, wpf, image, wpf-controls

Deleted my old question so I could make a more specific one. I am using code from http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/image-viewer-in-wpf/ as a basis. Lets a user browse for an image file to open and display. I want to display an image and then let the user make marks on it. I decided I want to use a canvas for this. Right now, I can't figure out how to get that user selected image as a background. I'm getting an error that says "System.Windows.Shapes.Path does not contain a definition for 'Background' and no extension method 'Background' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Shapes.Path' could be found..." from the line that says 'canvas1.Background = brush;". I've looked up ways to set the background of a canvas, some involving just using xaml code, but then I get other errors.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="CanvasStuff.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Main Window" Height="409" Width="574">
    <Grid >
        <Label Content="Image" Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="11,10,0,0"
               Name="selectedFileName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="393"
               Background="LightGray" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1"/>
        <Button Content="Browse File" Height="34" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="410,8,0,0"
                Name="BrowseButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="119"
                Foreground="Maroon" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Georgia" Click="BrowseButton_Click" />
        <Canvas>
            <Path Canvas.Left="61" Canvas.Top="28" Width="133" Height="98" Fill="Blue" 
            Stretch="Fill" Data="M61,125 L193,28" Name="canvas1"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
namespace CanvasStuff
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void BrowseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
            dlg.Filter = "Image files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
            dlg.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string selectedFileName = dlg.FileName;
                ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush();
                brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(selectedFileName, UriKind.Relative));
                canvas1.Background = brush; #error here
                BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use `UriKind.Absolute` instead, the selected file should of course be in some absolute path.

Comment: I changed it but I'm getting the same error. I don't think I'm using Name=canvas1 properly in my .xaml. When I mess around with that the .background error goes away but I get a canvas1 isn't used in current context error.

Comment: you are setting `Name` for the inner `Path`, not the `Canvas`, Why could that be so difficult naming problem for you?

Comment: Anyway my previous comment is still another problem of yours, don't believe? just keep your code and run it after you name your Canvas correctly.

Comment: Right, I just noticed that after looking at bonyjoe's example below. Had that path in there from a previous example and forgot to get rid of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "canvas1" element is a path, therefore it has a fill property rather than a background property, so you could replace canvas1.Background with canvas1.Fill. But this will not give you a background as that path only has a small size. You really want your window to have a background which you can do using an encompassing border.

```
<Window x:Class="CanvasStuff.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Main Window" Height="409" Width="574">
<Border x:Name="bgBorder" BorderThickness="0">
    <!-- insert your current content here -->
</Border>
</Window>
```

Then just replace

```
canvas1.Background = brush;
```

with

```
bgBorder.Background = brush;
```

Comment: Thank you! I have no idea why I had a path in there. I think I got it from looking at canvas examples, and just forgot about it. I got rid of it and fixed my .xaml up a bit and it works now.

Comment: @pfinferno really? still use `UriKind.Relative`?

Comment: I changed it like you said, that saved me from future problems. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, please mark as answer if you found it helpful. Also you can omit the UriKind altogether, the Uri(String) constuctor assumes UriKind.Absolute.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out thanks to bonyjoe and King King. My main issue was I forgot to take out the path (don't want it in there) that I was using on a previous example. So my canvas .xaml code looks like this now:

```
    <Canvas Margin="0,48,0,0" x:Name="canvas1">
    </Canvas>
```

This fixed what I was trying to do.